# Responsive columns with a fixed menu bar

Tags: html, css

I want to combine responsive elements with a semi-responsive element:

I want to have a menu bar at top having

```
height:10px;
width:100%;
```

And use the rest of the window for 9 **responsive rectangles** that will `float` left and resize based on the window size.

I know how to define these responsive squares, but I cannot figure out how to define the container size that will hold them.

In short, the container needs to be `100%` width and `100%` height minus the `10px` height of the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the height of container, css3 has a [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function. You can specify your containers height as

```
height: calc(100% - 10px);
```

CSS calc broswer support@ [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

---

You can have a fallback for browsers not supporting calc as follows:

```
height: 99%;
height: calc(100% - 10px);
```

check out this tutorial : [css calc](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Here's a simple  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5MS8/12)

---

Side note: if you want to specify height in %, you should give the parents elements height also in % starting from body,

```
html, body{
 height:100%;
}
```

Comment: this is what i have now, it does not seem to work. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJlDy

Comment: @user3387048  unfortunately that link is not loading, here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X5MS8/

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and i see the same problem. The content element, the green box, changes size based on the text inside. If there is no text, there is no green box. I would like to have the green box always full size which is 100% - 10px, so with the blue header box it would be 10px + (100% - 10px) = full window.

Comment: @user3387048 here's the very same fiddle with no content http://jsfiddle.net/X5MS8/1/

Comment: yes and now there is no green box at all... which is exactly what I DONT want. I think I cannot explain myself. I would like to have the green box cover all the rest of the window, even with no content.

Comment: I also checked in chrome and I cannot see the green box in the updated fiddle either.

Comment: @user3387048 it's working in chrome v 33.0.1750.146 , firefox 27.0, IE 10.
and supposed to work with all "modern" browsers with full css3 support. for older browsers, see the fallback method i mentioned.

Comment: @user3387048 i just checked your codepen in latest chrome and calc is working in it...

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, one css and one javascript:

css: (since the menu bar at the top is fixed I don't think you need to subtract off the height of the header if you write your html with the .container around the header and the section below)

```
html, body, .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

js: (on this one you could write you container as being outside the header, rather)

```
$(function() {
  $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
    $winHeight = $(window).height();
    $container = $('container');
    $container.height($winHeight - 10);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I would like to ask one more thing. I want to say "item height= container height * 0.33". How can I put that in js.

Comment: item = $container.height() * 0.33;